# How to execute binary type Mach-O on armv7l?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm

I am trying to execute a binary file that has type Mach-O, but it doesn't work!

My OS is:

> Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v7+ BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

And I tried to execute file as

> Mach-O armv7 executeable, flags:  < NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL>

Error:

> bash: ./roplevel1: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

What should I do? I am new! Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't run it directly. It is a binary produced for MacOS X, so it is the same like trying to run Windows .exe files on Linux.

There are ways to use Mach-O binaries, but it is always an emulator or something similar (like Wine for Windows binaries): https://github.com/shinh/maloader or http://www.darlinghq.org/

Comment: It’s more likely to be a binary for iOS, given that it targets ARM CPUs, but your main point stands.