# Why doesn’t binary compiled on M1 Mac (arm64) run on EC2 t4g.micro instance (aarch64)?

Tags: arm, amazon-ec2

Running [argon2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2) compile on M1 Mac on AWS t4g.micro instance running Debian throws following error.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47274698/4579271, `arm64` and `aarch64` refer to the same architecture.

```
$ ./argon2 -h
-bash: ./argon2: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: Did you compile your binary for macOS or for Debian?

Comment: For macOS I believe… I know little to nothing about cross compilation… somehow, I naively expected binary to work on Debian (`aarch64`) given it was compiled on `arm64` architecture.

Comment: @sunknudsen If it is the same architecture, you may be able to run a compatible Debian instance as a virtual machine and compile argon2 there before transferring it to Amazon.

Comment: Would you normally expect a x86_64 Linux binary to run on Windows, or a Windows .exe to run on MacOS? Those are also all the exact same architecture…

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It’s not enough to have a binary for the same hardware architecture; it also needs to target the appropriate software platform. A binary built for macOS on M1 won’t run on Debian, even on an M1 (let alone any other ARM64 CPU).

The specific error you’re getting is produced because your binary is a [Mach-O binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O); Linux systems expect ELF binaries. There are Mach-O loaders for Linux (see [How to execute binary type Mach-O on armv7l?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441294/86440)) but I don’t know whether they would allow you to run your specific binary.

(Loading the binary is just the first step; you also need any supporting libraries, and potentially system call emulation — [Maloader](https://github.com/shinh/maloader) avoids the latter by relying on the C library instead, binding the macOS program to the host-native C library, with a little translation; this works for any program which doesn’t issue system calls itself.)

Comment: As a mac user I get around this one with docker.  IE build in docker for desktop on the mac running a linux container.

Comment: Even with the same kind of binary, the libraries and syscalls would be different between Mac and Debian. It's the same reason why an x86 .exe from Windows wouldn't run on x86 Debian, at least without a translation layer like WINE

Comment: @小太郎 - Was going to say the same thing, but at least MacOS and Linux are both Unix-like OSes, so the emulation layer is probably a *lot* simpler than WINE, for programs that mostly make POSIX system calls (which would be typical for stuff you're running on a server).  IIRC, Linux used to have some support for running FreeBSD binaries directly (if they used the same architecture), effectively a simple compatibility layer built-in to the kernel.

Comment: @PeterCordes [FreeBSD can run Linux binaries](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/linuxemu/), I don’t think Linux has ever been able to run FreeBSD binaries. There was an iBCS2 compatibility layer a while back.

Comment: @StephenKitt: That's probably what I was remembering; now that you point that out, I seem to recall a previous time where I learned that I'd had this fact backwards. >.<

Comment: @小太郎 it’s not always necessary to handle system calls; if the program only ever issues system calls through C library wrappers, binding the native C library instead will take care of things.

Comment: @StephenKitt But even then, you need compatible ABIs.

Comment: @Barmar yes, and it turns out that the macOS C library ABI is compatible with the Linux GNU C library ABI in many cases (see Maloader).